# Losing Focus From A JTextField

Tags: focus, jpanel, jtextfield, keylistener, mouse-listeners

After I use my textfield I can't get a jpanel that click on back into focus for my keylistener. It works for the mouselistener but all other keystrokes keep being detected by the textfield not the jpanel.

The panel has been setFocusable(true) and works fine until i give the textfield the keyboard focus. It's like the textfield won't release the focus.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The answer was to call requestFocus() on the panel after the text action was performed.

Comment: please submit this comment as your answer and accept it so that it is clear this is a solution and that this question is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to call requestFocus() on the panel after the text action was performed